# For iPhone How to set the preferred content size for popovers with UINavigation Controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, popover

I am trying to customize the preferred content size of the popover (which is a UITableViewController with the embeded UINavigation Controller). I implemented the following code in the UITableViewController.

```
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillAppear(animated)

      let minimumSize = self.view.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 280, height: minimumSize.height)

     }

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
}
```

It is working fine on the iPad views but not on the iPhone views. for iPhone it is taking over the full screen not presenting as a pop over.
Any help on this would be much apprecaited.

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation is that you didn't set the delegate correctly, so the adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController is not called at all